# How to "log a call" in salesforce using REST API?

Tags: api, salesforce

I am trying to "log a call" in salesforce using REST API. Is it possible to do it with REST API and what is the exact end point?

Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inspect what's done in UI, check the ID of the generated record, then try to replicate it. From what I remember "log a call" action creates a completed Task record. Does the ID start with "00T"? http://www.fishofprey.com/2011/09/obscure-salesforce-object-key-prefixes.html

So [inserting](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_sobject_create.htm) a Task should get you close enough.

```
POST to https://MyDomainName.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v55.0/sobjects/Task/

with headers
    Authorization: Bearer <session id goes here>
    Content-Type: application/json

and body
{
  "Subject": "Sample call",
  "Type": "Call",
  "TaskSubtype" : "Call",
  "CallType" : "Outbound",
  "Status" : "Closed",
  "WhoId" : "003... put contact id here?"
}
```

Should be good start. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_task.htm is decent info although your org might need more (record types? required fields? different picklist values?)

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. I was trying this also, this was giving error 
{ "message": "No such column 'Type' on sobject of type Task", "errorCode":"INVALID_FIELD"}

Comment: Can you query it? `SELECT Id, Subject, Type FROM Task LIMIT 10`? I suspect your connecting user's profile / permission sets don't include the permission to see/edit this field

Comment: Thanks, but for this query i need ID, how should i get this ? 
This Id is account ID of salesforce ? for which specific account the task is assigned, something like this ?

Comment: how to give permission to user ?

Comment: You don't need ID, you can run it without WHERE clause. If you really want - navigate to account, write down the "001..." part of the URL and then `SELECT Id, Subject, Type FROM Task WHERE AccountId = '001....'`. To grant access for example for system administrators -> Go to Setup -> Profiles -> System Administrator -> Object Settings -> Task -> field level security. https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/data_security/data_security_fields might help

Comment: can we "log a call" using bulk API ?

Comment: It's still an insert operation. You feed to bulk API CSV or JSON from what I remember, there should be examples of inserting say accounts, just adapt it a bit? Change column names and good to go? JSON payload probably identical to mine, maybe wrapped in array of objects